# How to build OpenSeaMap/renderer on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: openstreetmap, java, tiles, rendering

I have set up a tile server on ubuntu 14.04, downloaded the openstreetmap-carto style and compliled it with carto. Then I customized the renderd.conf file like this:

```
[renderd]
socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
num_threads=4
tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
stats_file=/var/run/renderd.stats

[mapnik]
plugins_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input
font_dir=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu
font_dir_recurse=1

[default]
URI=/osm_tiles/
TILEDIR=/var/lib/mod_tile
XML=/usr/local/share/maps/style/....../osmcarto.xml
HOST=localhost
TILESIZE=256
```

Now apache together with the mod_tile module deliver tiles to the client.

I have found in [git](https://github.com/OpenSeaMap/renderer/tree/master/work) a renderer (used from openseamap) for the elements with seamark tags which is written in java and has no installation instructions.

I have only figured out that in order to build searender on ubuntu as a first step I have to run the command "make -f Makefile.linux".

Does anyone know what else must be done in order to build and run searender successfully on ubuntu 14.04?

I also know that jsearch and jtile need to be build with Apache ant and moved or linked to the jar files in work/.

How may I accomplish this?

Is it possible to have both renderers(the one that I have already and the openseamap/renderer) running on the same machine and produce two different tile sets(/osm_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png which I already have  and tiles produced from openseamap/renderer which will be used as an overlay in my map)?